# Nginx + PHP: When I try to call a function in an included file the script dies

Tags: php, function, nginx, error-reporting

I've got a new server with Nginx installed instead of Apache.  On that server I have a functions.php script with a list of PHP functions common in my code.  My code looks something like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
echo "1";
include_once('../functions.php');
echo "2";
echo getHelloWorld(); // this is found in functions.php, simply returns "hello world"
echo "3";
```

When I hit the page on my browser, however, all that prints is `12`, indicating two things:

1. The script died when it tried calling `getHelloWorld()` and
2. The error reporting seems to have done nothing

I've tried the various different types of error reporting without success (as found here: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and I've also confirmed (many times) that the `getHelloWorld()` function is spelled correctly, error-free, etc.

I'm very new to Nginx, so if anyone can give me any clues as to what might be going on I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: You should check the error log or try to display the errors directly in your script: `ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: Honestly, I thought that was what `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` was supposed to do.  That's what I get for coding at 2am...

Comment: No, you are just setting the level of error reporting / what is logged, but the "standard" error reporting is to the error log, not to the screen.

Comment: If you'd like to submit that as an answer I'll accept it.  It lead me to the fix for this issue (simple typo in an imported file), now onto the others!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` you set the level of error reporting / what is logged.

If you want to show the errors in your script, you need to set:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Otherwise the errors will be logged to the error log only (normally...).